# Android Monerujo wallet doesn't detect monero wallet files from another phone

Tags: wallet-recovery, android-wallet, monerujo, android

I got a new phone and installed Monerujo, but the old wallet files from another phone located in the Monerujo folder isn't be being detected on the new phone even though the directory structure is the same. Is there a specific folder that these wallet files need to be in?

Comment: Did you try the FAQ: [Can I use existing wallet files?](https://github.com/m2049r/xmrwallet/blob/master/doc/FAQ.md#can-i-use-existing-wallet-files) Also, is the Storage permission enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [FAQ](https://github.com/m2049r/xmrwallet/blob/ac70ba84248887853677cb958547ea23ddc1a054/doc/FAQ.md#can-i-use-existing-wallet-files):

> If you want to use existing wallet files, you need to copy the wallet
> files from you current Monero client. These are:
>
> WalletName
>
> WalletName.address.txt
>
> WalletName.keys

You need to zip these files up and monerujo will detect it when you select "import wallet".